# Collection View gets progressively slower as I insert more and more items into it

Tags: ios, swift, performance, core-data, uicollectionview

So I'm building a messaging app using JSQMessagesViewController. I linked it to fetchedResultsController which tracks every time I insert a new object into the context. In didPressSend is where I insert into context:

```
    override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {
    let message = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Message", into: context) as! Message
    message.text = text
    message.timestamp = Date() as NSDate?


}
```

So everytime I insert the new object into the context using DidPressSend (The send button), fetched results controller gets fired up

```
var InsertOperation = [BlockOperation]()
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    if type == .insert {

        InsertOperation.append(BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in

            self?.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            self?.collectionView.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath!])
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
            }

            }))


    }



}
```

The block operation is then executed in didChangeContent

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

   collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ 
    for operation in self.InsertOperation {
    operation.start()
    self.InsertOperation.removeFirst()

    }
    })

}
```

This finally inserts the item into the collection view that was created in didPressSend. At first, it inserts them with phenomenal speed. Everything works amazing!. However, as I get to 100 or so items in the collectionView it starts to get more and more sluggish. I don't have anything fancy going on in my collectionView delegate methods. Simply what's required as such:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    let msg : Message = fetchedResultsControler.object(at: indexPath) as! Message
    let messageData = JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderDisplayName, text: msg.text)
    return messageData
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (fetchedResultsControler.sections?[0].numberOfObjects)!
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

    return cell
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    let bubbleFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
    return bubbleFactory?.outgoingMessagesBubbleImage(with: .black)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    return nil
}
```

I have not included this in the code, but when the user presses the back button, and comes back to the chat, it paginates the chat only showing the last 20 messages, making it superfast again. However, it is very possible that the user may send a lot of messages before pressing back and giving the collection view the chance to paginate. As a result user experience would seriously diminish as the person is chatting. I noticed that apps like tinder, (I tested it), you can send 1000 messages at once, and nothing would slow down. There must be a trick that I can't figure out. 
Thank you!

Comment: why do you `invalidate` `collectionView's` layout every time you send a message?

Comment: Hi Adeel, I took that off as I just realized i dont actually need it at all. However, this does not solve the performance problem.